# DGET is not successfully matching criteria in Time format

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to use DGET() to match values across several sheets.

If I try and match criteria that are times, it always fails. If I replace the criteria with words, it is successful. Here is an image as an example:

[image]

The one that failed was trying to match the time of `7:00 AM` and the one that worked is matching the words `StuffStuff`. If I do an `IF` statement between the two times, it is `TRUE`.

How do I get DGET to work with times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it without `"="&` like this:

```
=DGET(F60:M61,"Sat",{"Start Time";F67})
```

Comment: This works best if you have only numeric values in your column. However, if you had also strings *beginning with the same letter*, let's say `StuffStuff` and `s`, and you wanted to search for `s`, you would get an error indicating that more than one match was found. To make this formula work well on both, strings and numeric values, I would incorporate the part you used before with an `IF`, like this: `=DGET(F60:M61,"Sat",{"Start Time";IF(ISNUMBER(F67),F67,"="&F67)})`